# Nested Chaning promise response getting undefined in Controller by using UI Route resolve

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

for past 3 days , i have struggling in getting a value from nested service through controller,

I have a service 1 call and pass the service 1 call to service 2 and getting a response and pass to controller,In controller , i am getting undefined.

So when i pass a single response call , that means service1 call , getting a value in controller by using Ui route resolve.

What wrong here ?

This is my factory call.

```
app.factory('LogHomService', function (Service1, Service2)
{
    var MyService = function (data)
    {

   Service1.log("user", encodeURIComponent("ad"))
        .then(function(response) {
          var FullUrl = response.strURL;
          var objs = response.products; // getting the response here

         Service2.pageLoad(objs)
            .then(function(response) {
               var homeScreen = response; // getting the response here 
               return homeScreen;

                        });
                     });

        };

    return {

            MyService:  MyService
        }
});
```

Route call:

```
.state('home.prod', {
  url: '/product',
  views: {
    '@': {
      templateUrl: baseUrl + 'home/product',
      controller: 'productController'
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    param2: function(LogHomService) {
      return LogHomService.MyService();
    }
  }
})
```

Controller:

```
var productController = function ($scope, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams,param2)
{
       console.log(param2); // getting undefined
}
productController.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$state','$stateParams','param2');
```

**Note:**
When I return a single response getting a value in controller which means return a service 1 call getting response.

When i tried to return a service2 call getting undefined.

This is my factory call.

```
app.factory('LogHomService', function (Service1, Service2)
{
    var MyService = function (data)
    {

   Service1.log("user", encodeURIComponent("ad"))
        .then(function(response) {
          var FullUrl = response.strURL;
          var objs = response.products; // getting the response here

        return objs;
            });
        };

    return {

            MyService:  MyService
        }
});
```

Comment: I don't think you should directly call the service in the resolve, you have: `return LogHomService.MyService()`, try `return LogHomService.MyService`

Comment: thanks,Now in params getting  function call MyService there, how can i get the second service response data? in param2 in controller?

Comment: Store the data that gets loaded in the request in the factory itself so that it will be there when it gets resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your question in the comments, in order to access the data in the service in your controller, you could do something like this:

```
app.factory('LogHomService', function (Service1, Service2) {
   var service = {}
   service.myMethod = function (data) {
     Service1.log("user", encodeURIComponent("ad"))
        .then(function(response) {
          var FullUrl = response.strURL;
          //at this point, you will have access to LogHomService.objs
          service.objs = response.products; 
          return service.objs;
         });
      };

    return service
});
```

Comment: I have tried your solution, In controller console.log(param2) when debugging its showing function LogHomeService.myMethod(data) in the data showing this code factory code not return a response value. something went wrong why its showing script instead of response in controller  param2

Comment: So i tried simple return string  in factory , gets in controller `app.factory('LogHome', function (Service1, Service2) {
    var service = {};
    service.MyService = function (response) {

    return "HelloWorld"
      
    };
    return service;
});` its working when i use the function call in resove 
`resolve: {
    param2: function(LogHomService) {
      return LogHomService.MyService();
    }` when i tried to give this return LogHomService.MyService return function.

Comment: So what data are you trying to get into the controller via the resolve?

Comment: Thanks man for your replies at last this code is working with your latest factory code
resolve: {
    param2: function(LogHomService) {
      return LogHomService.MyService();
    }

Comment: @reptilicius if you know pls help me to this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994004/how-to-form-the-query-string-in-web-address-url-in-angular-state-router-by-using

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
return LogHomService.MyService();
```

will always return null because `MyService` function returns nothing.

Here is a purposed fix:

```
var MyService = function (){
 return Service1.log("user", encodeURIComponent("ad"))
    .then(function(response) {
      var FullUrl = response.strURL;
      var objs = response.products;
      return Service2.pageLoad(objs);
    };
}
```

I've also cleared some unnecessary stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Service2 object response from the controller,In controller getting Function call when i use return LogHomService.MyService; if i use return LogHomService.MyService(); shows undefined. i will attached the screenshot below.

But in Service response have values , Don't know why.[image]

When I click the data , its shows factory code.